# Проблема с ошибкой list index out of range

Tags: python

Это часть программы по распознаванию лиц. Написал код не я и за основу взял код из github и делал по примеру, было много ошибок которые я решал то определенного момента, пока не встретилась эта. Пытался так найти в интернете, но и близкого того что я делаю нету. PyCharm ругается на 12 строчку не знаю почему.
ndarray не было в основе кода, добавил по подсказки которые автоматически появляются когда появляются ошибки, но даже так не помогло. Эта часть кода отвечает, за само распознавание. Добавил 2 человек с начало для теста, но как я понял при формирование списка людей которых надо распознать выдаётся ошибка.

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
from numpy import ndarray

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("files/video.mp4")

# Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
Mikhail = face_recognition.load_image_file("files/me.jpg")
Mikhail_encoding: ndarray = face_recognition.face_encodings(Mikhail)[0]

# Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
Trump = face_recognition.load_image_file("files/tramp.png")
Trump_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(Trump)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    Trump_encoding,
    Mikhail_encoding
]

known_face_names = [
    "Mikhail",
    "Trump"
]
```

Comment: Может `Mikhail_encoding: ndarray = face_recognition.face_encodings(Alexey)[0]` тут изменить `Alexey` на `Mikhail`? Так как переменной `Alexey` нету и мой вам совет начинайте с азов.

Comment: нет, не в этом дело это я забыл поменять когда не понимал в чём проблема и полностью под копирку делал, с азов начну когда доделаю это с начало,  а так спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот это :

```
Mikhail_encoding: ndarray = face_recognition.face_encodings(Alexey)[0]
```

не соответствует синтаксису Python.
Исправьте, хотя-бы, на так:

```
Mikhail_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(Alexey)[0]
```

А про "с азов начну когда доделаю это с начало" -  подумайте как выглядит, например, хирург, который говорит "вот этого пациента прооперирую и начну учить анатомию", или водитель, который говорит - "вот сейчас проеду через весь город и пойду начну  учиться водить машину".  Вот вы сейчас выглядите примерно так-же.

Comment: Полностю согласен с вашими словами!

Comment: Нет, всё равно ругается на ту строчку. А по поводу примеров что вы привели, там как минимум зависит судьба человека, а то того что я делаю кому хуже?  Я за это взялся не потому что хотел кому то, что то доказать и показать что я сразу разберусь в программировании, были свои причины почему мне пришлось взять эту тему, но это тема отдельного разговора, но так или иначе всё равно спасибо.

Comment: И будет ругаться, пока вы не выучите Python с азов. И не поймете как отлавливать ошибки. Какими и почему они бывают. Вот вам сказали выше -  замените Alexey, ибо нет такого объекта. Потом я сказал, как исправить синтаксис. Но додуматься объединить эти два совета, что-бы "не ругалось на ту строчку" вы пока, без понимания азов, не можете. А про примеры -  я не про то, жизнь или нет там зависят. А про то, кем выглядит человек, не умеющий ничего (реально ничего) и хватающийся за все. Ну, что-бы понятнее было - строящий самолет и не знающий законы физики. Так понятнее? Дальше -  думайте сами.

Comment: чувак я не хочу что то тут разводить. Как я писал раннее ошибки которые раньше выскакивали, я с ними справлялся и без азов Python, но я не нашёл в инете именно эту проблему решил написать сюда. И да вы же в себе так уверены, что я такой глупый не додумался совместить 2 этих решения. Молодец, флаг тебе в руки, медаль придёт по почте. Как бы не хотелось тебе назвать чсв, но не получается. Заешь про меня по паре сообщений, всё знаешь, всё видел, везде трогал, иди в полицию зачем тебе программирование, людей понимаешь только взглянув с такими навыками ты там пригодишься.

Comment: @passant, `Mikhail_encoding: ndarray = face_recognition.face_encodings(Alexey)[0]` вполне соответствует синтаксису Python. Если убрать из ответа это утверждение, как неверное, то остальное - это скорее комментарий, никак не отвечающий на вопрос.

Comment: @Михаил "все равно ругается на эту строчку" - это не текст ошибки. Чтобы вам могли помочь, нужно указать конкретный текст ошибки в вопросе. Текст ошибки пишется для того, чтобы его читать.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VaditelCatofalki\Desktop\recognition test\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    Mikhail_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(Mikhail)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1`  вот полная ошибка, как я и говорил ругается на 12 строчку

Comment: Чего и следовало ожидать, если исходить из принципа "я с ними справлялся и без азов Python". А те, кто понимают, что любой навык надо нарабатывать  "с азов"  с такими ошибками знакомятся на втором занятии и понимают, о чем говорят эти сообщения. А говорят они о том, что в составном объекте (в данном случае - списке) вы пытаетесь обратиться по индексу к элементу, которого в этом списке нет. Другими словами - ваш список, который формируется функцией face_encoding - пуст. Т.е. на  фото распознанных  лиц нет.  Но вы продолжайте "оперировать не зная анатомии" - это даже очень забавно выглядит.